# Idiomatic Way To Merge Trait Functionality

Tags: scala

Suppose I have the following:

```
abstract class Service {}
case class Blue() extends Service
case class Green() extends Service
case class Red() extends Service

abstract trait Material {
  def supports(s: Service): Service
}

trait Wood extends Material {
  def supports(s: Service): Boolean = {
    s match {
      case _:Blue => false
      case _:Green => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}

trait Stone extends Material {
  def supports(s: Service): Boolean = {
    s match {
      case _:Blue => true
      case _:Green => false
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is have a type `MyService` that is both `Stone` and `Wood`, such that `MyService.supports(service)` will return `true` if `service` is either `Blue` or `Green`, but `false` if it is `Red`:

```
case class MyService() extends Wood with Stone
service = new MyService()
service.supports(new Blue()) //true
service.supports(new Green()) //true
service.supports(new Red()) //false
```

Obviously the above creates a conflict because both `Wood` and `Stone` implement the same method. I could create a new `trait StoneAndWood`, but that seems inelegant. Is there an elegant way of merging those two functions (essentially putting a boolean `or` between them?). Would a different class design make this task easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having each subclass of `Material` call its superclass's `supports` method if it doesn't support the service? Something like this:

```
abstract trait Material {
  def supports (s: Service) = false
}

trait Wood extends Material {
  override def supports (s: Service) = 
   s match { 
    case _: Green => True; 
    case _       => super supports s
 }
}

trait Stone extends Material {
  override def supports (s: Service) = 
   s match { 
     case _: Blue => True; 
     case _       => super supports s
 }
}
```

Comment: How does this address the question about `case class MyService() extends Wood with Stone`? That still doesn't work, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
class WoodStone extends Wood with Stone {
  override def supports(s: Service): Boolean = {
    super[Wood].supports(s) || super[Stone].supports(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, as I noted at the end of the question this works. But supposing a large variety of `Material` sub-traits, which can all be mixed into a particular class, this becomes unwieldy.